# Error when attempting to reassign crs with raster::projectRaster: error in rbind:number of columns of matrices must match

Tags: projection, r-raster, rbind

I have the following SpatRaster object called pred_th.

```
dimensions  : 162, 87, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.08333333, 0.08333333  (x, y)
extent      : 43.25, 50.5, -25.58333, -12.08333  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source(s)   : memory
name        :  lyr1 
min value   : FALSE 
max value   :  TRUE
```

I'm trying to reassign the crs to ESPG 2970. When I attempt the following using the `raster` function `projectRaster`:

```
  projectRaster(crs = "EPSG:29702", method = 'ngb') -> pred_th_proj
```

I receive this error message:

```
Error in rbind(xy1, xy2, xy3, xy4, xy5) : 
number of columns of matrices must match (see arg 5)
```

I'm very stumped, if anyone could help this would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: When asking an R question, please provide a *minimal, self-contained, reproducible example* using data generated by code or data that ships with R (see the help files for examples).

Answer (score 1):

There is no `projectRaster` method for "SpatRaster" objects. You are probably looking for

```
pred_th_proj <- project(x, "EPSG:29702", method = "near")
```

where `x` is your SpatRaster